# Select option with input text

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I try to use input text for select option and i found this script from google

```html
<input type="text" list="airports" name="airports"> 
<datalist id="airports">
<option value="Berlin">
<option value="Los Angeles">
<option value="Moscow">
<option value="Paris">
</datalist>
<input type="submit" value="confirm">
```

Here my script before :

```html
<?php
$first="select * from members";
$two=mysql_query($first)or die("You Die!"); ?>
<select>
<? while($three=mysql_fetch_array($two)){ ?>
<option value=<? echo $three['firstname'];?><? echo $three['firstname'];?></option>
<? } ?>
</select>
```

When i combine them :

```html
<?php
$first="select * from members";
$two=mysql_query($first)or die("You Die!"); ?>
<select>
<input type="text" list="firstname" name="firstname">
<datalist id="firstname">
<? while($three=mysql_fetch_array($two)){ ?>
<option value=<? echo $three['firstname'];?>><? echo $three['firstname'];?></option>
<? } ?>
</datalist>
</select>
```

it doest work t_t"

Comment: mysql_ library is deprecated. It is recommended that you use mysqli or PDO

Comment: The bottom code has a select tag while the first one doesn't, is that intentional?

Comment: @AmmarAslam Aw thank you bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
<?php
$first="select * from members";
$two=mysql_query($first)or die("You Die!"); ?>
<select>
<input type="text" list="firstname" name="firstname">
<datalist id="firstname">
<? while($three=mysql_fetch_array($two)){ ?>
<option value="<? echo $three['firstname'];?>">
<? } ?>
</datalist>
</select>
```